# How to change the height of the container according to its child in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the container height dynamically ie., according to its child 
For example: If I have a container and grid view as a child. What if the grid has 4 grids in the first case and 5 grids in the second case. So how do I fit the grid view in a container? How to changes its height according to the child.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't provide Container a specific height;
Also, you can use constraints to set min and max width and height

```
Container(constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 5.0,
    minWidth: 5.0,
    maxHeight: 30.0,
    maxWidth: 30.0,
  ),child: ,)
```

Comment: if I give these constraints, will it automatically adjust the height?

Comment: yes and if you want container to fill its parent widget's size then don't provide height or width parameter at all. Containers are by default set to take all available space of their parent widget

Comment: I tried without giving any height and box constraints, it didn't work for me.